# VirtualBox docker images performance issues

Tags: docker

I'm experimenting with the new docker setup on macOS Monteray. To be short I've moved docker daemon into VirtualBox, here is some setup details:

- Vagrant + VirtualBox (with the latest Ubuntu LTS);
- Dockerd runs on Ubuntu (inside VirtualBox);
- I have docker client on the host (macOS)
- Host and guest docker client versions are matching

I've built images from my java project within VB and everything works fine.
I did exactly the same, but from host os, and as a result, I have some serious performance degradation with newly built images.

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to overcome these issues?

Comment: Are you mounting the file system from the host to the container in the second case?

Comment: No. But I've tried to build a project from a mounted directory WITHIN VB and it worked fine

Comment: Docker-on-MacOS uses Xhyve as its virtualization subsystem. It's a different, smaller tool; it's not expected that their behavior will be identical.

Comment: Now, what _is_ worth looking into is whether VirtualBox is able to virtualize at all or is falling back to CPU emulation -- if, say, Xhyve's kernel plugin is already loaded, it might block the VirtualBox one. But that's not on-topic here; Stack Overflow is only for questions about writing code and using tools that are exclusively for software development purposes; VirtualBox has plenty of uses outside the software development world.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. To be clear, I have no Docker Desktop on my host os, only docker client binary. MacOS docker somehow builds images which is platform-dependent?